# Building a sorting of student marks using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My sample table:

```
student_name subject marks
    a          x      90
    a          y      95 
    b          x      89
    b          y      99
    c          x      91
    c          y      96
```

I need the output in a way that sum(marks) of student, then order in descending.

for example a(90+95) = 185, b(89+99) = 188, c(91+96) = 187

So order of the output is:

```
student_name subject marks
    b          x      89
    b          y      99
    c          x      91
    c          y      96
    a          x      90
    a          y      95
```

I am new to SQL Server. Can you help me in building this query?

```
Select student_name, subject, marks
sum(marks) as total
from table order by total desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by joining the table with the sum of marks for each student and then order by the total in descending order.

**Query**

```
select [t1].* from [your_table_name] as [t1]
join (
  select [student_name], sum([marks]) as [total]
  from [your_table_name]
  group by [student_name]
) as [t2]
on [t1].[student_name] = [t2].[student_name]
order by [t2].[total] desc;
```

**[Find a demo here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1170707/building-a-sorting-of-student-marks-using-sql)**

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
SELECT a.student_name
    ,a.subject
    ,a.marks
    ,(
        SELECT sum(marks)
        FROM TABLE b
        WHERE a.student_name = b.student_name
        GROUP BY b.student_name
        )
FROM TABLE a
ORDER BY 4 DESC
    ,a.student_name
    ,a.marks ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a window function in the `order by`:

```
Select student_name, subject, marks
from table
order by sum(marks) over (partition by student_name) desc,
         student_name, subject;
```

Note the additional keys in the `order by`.  This keeps each student together when several students have the same total.

If you wanted the sum in the results as well:

```
Select student_name, subject, marks,
       sum(marks) over (partition by student_name) as total_marks
from table
order by total_marks desc, student_name;
```